# Goroutines run inside another function

Tags: go

It may be a silly question, but I just wonder,

**code:**

```
func sumNumber(value int){
    array1 := []int{3, 6, 7)

    for _, v:= range array1{
        go anotherFunction(v) // goroutine function is run three times 
    }
}
```

My question is, Which one will finish first, func sumNumber or goroutine anotherFunction?

Comment: Nobody knows and anything is possible.

Comment: First of all, there are 3 goroutines running there.  So you have actually 4 functions waiting to finish. And when concurrency is in the talks nothing has a simple answer.

Comment: Note that "goroutine anotherFunction" is meaningless. Goroutines aren't named. And in fact, in your example, you have three goroutines executing the anotherFunction function.

Comment: https://gobyexample.com/worker-pools u can find unswers to your question here

Answer (score 3):

This completely depends on so many factors,especially on what "anotherFunction" does. However the sumNumber function definitely is going to be very short lived as it is just going to initiate three go routines and exit.

Comment: (It's possible and legitimate for all three goroutines to run to completion before control gets handed back to the calling function.)